# I asked one author for a resource related to their paper - is it okay to also ask a coauthor?

Tags: etiquette, email

I recently communicated with an author asking for some resources related to their research paper. He responded to the mail and the response contains:

1. Appreciation for the interest.
2. Resource may be available with another author.
3. Resource may be available to all in the near future, and so monitor the corresponding sites frequently.

I am confused whether to ask another author for the resource based on point 2, or to wait based on point 3.

Is it okay to communicate with the second author (despite the information provided in point 3) due to my urgency?

Answer (score 6):

I would email the other author ("Author B"), mention you were in contact with "Author A" and they suggested either the resource might be available with them (Author B) or available publicly soon. Make clear (but briefly) *exactly* what it is you would want/need.

In most cases its impolite to forward private email chains to others, but if all you have on this email chain is 2 messages: your initial ask and the response you described here, I think it would be fine to forward this email to Author B showing your previous correspondence with Author A. But still be clear about what you want so that Author B doesn't need to dig through it to find out, that can be really annoying.

I wouldn't mention any urgency; to paraphrase a common saying, your urgency or need is not their emergency. It's fine to *ask*, just not to *demand*, and I wouldn't beg or say you need it by XYZ date. Do not say "Author A said you would..." - they didn't, they said it *might* be available.

Probably Author B will respond with something similar to point (3), but maybe you'll get lucky. As long as you aren't sending many emails pestering them, one email to Author B after your one email to Author A is just fine.

Comment: +1 specifically for "its impolite to forward private email chains". I once received a forward from a colleague, with one of the mails down the chain literally began with "please keep it confidential between you and me".